# Are Bond cycles Dansgaard-Oeschger event(s)?

Tags: climate

Are the c.1500 year cyclical climate cycles called bond cycles or Dansgaard-Oeschger event(s)? I thought the Dansgaard-Oeschger event(s)? occur on much longer timescales. If so, why are they also called bond cycles? What is the correct terminology? Thank you.

Comment: The Wikipedia articles seem to explain the distinction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dansgaard%E2%80%93Oeschger_event AND https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_event